# Express - Environment Debugging In Routes

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, routes, environment-variables

I've been working on a basic web app using Express, and have been using the recommended `app.get('env')` for debugging purposes:

```
var app = require('express')();
...
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        // code to run when in development
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now that I've started modularizing my code into routes, I lose access to the `app` object in favour of `router`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Since `.get('env')` is part of `app`, I cannot figure out how to get the debug environment state from within a route.  How can I obtain this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct approach in ExpressJS 4 is:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' === env) {
   // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Bit confused; I tried the following in app.js:
`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV, process.env.DEBUG, app.get('env'))`
and got the first two to be "undefined" but the last to be "development".  Does 'env' default to development for some reason?

Comment: Answer: Yes.  From the doc: 'env - Environment mode, defaults to process.env.NODE_ENV (NODE_ENV environment variable) or "development"'